# Test finished without running any assertion (ava-nodejs)

Tags: node.js, testing, promise, async-await, ava

Why does this test return *Test finished without running any assertion*? Something wrong with promise handling? If i run this code on server everything works properly.

```
test.serial('test with req' , async (assert) => {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  request('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=5&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new',
    (error, response, body) => {
      console.log(response)
      if(!error){
        resolve(body)
      } else {
        reject(error)
      }
    })
  })

  promise.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    assert.true(result !== undefined)
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    assert.true(err !== undefined)
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `ava`, however, you mark the test body as `async`.... but don't seem to `await` anything - thinking perhaps you should be `await`ing the promise rather than `then`?

Comment: @turb alo, Can you please post your test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `request` already has promise support, you can rewrite this full test in 2 lines using `async` / `await`

```
test.serial('test with req' , async (assert) => {
  const result = await request('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=5&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new');
  assert.true(result !== undefined);
})
```

Comment: @turbato the result of `await request(...)` is the body